# How do I conditionally format an Excel sheet based on another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have 2 dataframes that I want to save as 2 sheets in a new Excel workbook.

`df1` =

| Column 1A | Column 1B | Column 2A | Column 2B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | First1 | Third | Third |
| Second | Second | Fourth1 | Fourth |

Some context: I created `df2` to indicate the differences between Column 1A and Column 1B, as well as Column 2A and column 2B. TRUE indicates that Column 1A and 1B are different, and FALSE indicates that the value in Column 1A and 1B are the same.

`df2` =

| Column 1 | Column 1B | Column 2A | Column 2B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | TRUE | Third | FALSE |
| Second | FALSE | Fourth1 | TRUE |

What I want to do is to output an excel workbook where the differences are highlighted in `df1`. To do this, I created an excel workbook with both sheets, and conditionally formatted sheet1(`df1`) according to sheet2 (`df2`).

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx', engine ='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = df1)
ws1 = writer.sheets[df1]

df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = df2)
ws2 = writer.sheets[df2]
condition = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':xxxx})
ws1.conditional_format('A1:XFD1048576', {'type' :'formula','criteria' : '=df2!A1 = TRUE', 'format' = condition})

ws2.hide()
```

However, this returned an error `Removed Feature: Conditional f formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part`

But when I tried to do the conditional formatting manually in Excel using the rule `='df2!A1=TRUE'`, it worked perfectly. What have I done wrongly, or is there was any way I could do this task more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of syntax and other errors in your code. Once they are fixed the conditional format should work as expected. Here is a version of your program with some sample data and the issues fixed:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1A': ['First', 'Second'],
                    'Column 1B': ['First1', 'Second'],
                    'Column 2A': ['Third', 'Forth1'],
                    'Column 2B': ['Fourth', 'Forth']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1A': ['First', 'Second'],
                    'Column 1B': [True, False],
                    'Column 2A': ['Third', 'Forth1'],
                    'Column 2B': [False, True]})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2')

workbook = writer.book
ws1 = writer.sheets['df1']
ws2 = writer.sheets['df2']
condition = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})

ws1.conditional_format('A1:XFD1048576',
                       {'type': 'formula',
                        'criteria': '=df2!A1 = TRUE',
                        'format': condition})

ws2.hide()

writer.save()
```

**Output**:
[image]